# Intercept websocket initial handshake in rsockets

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, rsocket

I want to be able to intercept the first request a client makes to my endpoint so to be able to answer with 101 (websocket estabilished) or deny it.

Is there any interceptor I can use? I tried registering a filter bean but it seems it is just skipped, I think because I'm in a webflux application...

```
 @Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<ContextFilter> initialFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<ContextFilter> registrationBean
            = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();

    registrationBean.setFilter(new MyFilter());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registrationBean.setOrder(1);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

and

```
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    log.info("You know, for filtering");
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

}
```

Comment: you should not use a filter to solve this problem because websockets is not HTTP so a filter can't intercept, but also, the filter you have chosen is not a webflux filter. Just wanted you to know that. `OncePerRequestFilter` is not used in webflux. You have to use the `WebFilter` class if you want a HTTP filter in webflux. You can read more about it here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-filters

Comment: I know, but I'd like to block the initial http request, the one containing the switch protocol request, based on some headers values. From the websocket on it will be ok to not intercept anything anymore

Answer (score 1):

To establish the RSocket connection client must send a first frame called SETUP frame. You can catch it with the Spring `@ConnectMapping` annotation.

```kotlin
    @ConnectMapping
    fun onConnect(rSocketRequester: RSocketRequester, clientId: String) {
        if (clientId == "wrong_client") rSocketRequester.rsocket().dispose()   //to reject connection
    }
```

To reject the connection use the `rSocketRequester.rsocket().dispose()` as shown above.
Note that with the SETUP frame you can pass the payload and metadata from the client as usual.

Comment: Is it also possible to see request headers or query string parameters?

Comment: Can't understand how to use it though...do I need to register it somewhere?

Comment: You can use it in `@Controller` file. You can also have many `@ConnetctMapping("specify-route-here")` and use client metadata to decide which one to use. It should act like a simple `@MessageMapping`, please check it in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#rsocket-annot-responders-client

Comment: Anyway it seems I cannot see url params/headers, not even getting the initial rsocket

Comment: Show me the code of how you pass the data and metadata from the client with rsocket

Comment: I just do new WebSocket("http://server/url?param1=a"). I would need to extract that param1. Also, there's an http proxy inbetween that will add an header to the connection upgrade request. I also need to intercept that

Comment: Can you please provide me links with example of use? Can't find it on the github...

Comment: http://kojotdev.com/2019/09/rsocket-examples-java-javascript-spring-webflux/

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the first request by implementing `WebSocketHandler` and using `ServerHttpRequest` you can access headers and query parameters from the request and can modify the response using `ServerHttpResponse` to return a `101` status code.

```
import io.rsocket.RSocket;
import io.rsocket.core.RSocketServer;
import io.rsocket.transport.netty.server.CloseableChannel;
import io.rsocket.transport.netty.server.WebsocketServerTransport;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.server.support.WebSocketHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig {

    @Bean
    public RSocket rSocket() {
        // Your RSocket bean configuration
        return RSocketServer.create()
                .bind(WebsocketServerTransport.create("localhost", 8080))
                .start()
                .block();
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping webSocketHandlerMapping() {
        Map<String, WebSocketHandler> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("/rsocket", new CustomWebSocketHandler());

        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setOrder(1);
        mapping.setUrlMap(map);
        return mapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
        return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter();
    }

    private static class CustomWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

        @Override
        public CloseableChannel handle(ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {
            // Access headers and query parameters here
            String headerValue = serverHttpRequest.getHeaders().getFirst("your-header");
            String queryParamValue = serverHttpRequest.getQueryParams().getFirst("your-query-param");

            // Modify the response to return 101 status code
            serverHttpResponse.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS);

            // Implement your logic here

            return null; // Return the CloseableChannel or handle as needed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this solution works with rsocket?

Comment: My mistake, I missed `rsocket` part. Modified my answer